# How to open a document not from xpage link?

Tags: xpages

I have created a xpage to display a view, and I set the second column as "show values in this column as links". So the second column was shown as a link when I preview in web browser, and when I move the cursor to the link, the IE browser status dispaly (xxx.com/oas/JTJ.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=AABBCCDD12345678&action=openDocument).

[image]

But now I don't want to open the document via xpage, I want to open the document with the link like this (xxx.com/oas/JTJ.nsf/0/AABBCCDD12345678?OpenDocument) from the above picture's xpage link.

[image]

How could I do?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `<xp:link ...>` into your `<xp:viewColumn> ... </xp:viewColumn>` and calculate the URL based on `rowData.getColumnValue("yourColumnName")` and
`rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID()` / `rowData.getColumnValue("unid")` .

Comment: I don't want to get the column value. I want to open the document via htp://xxx.com/oas/JTJ.nsf/0/AABBCCDD12345678?OpenDocument instead of htp://xxx.com/oas/JTJ.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=AABBCCDD12345678&action=openDocument in the xpage.

Comment: Look here for an example how to add a calculated link to viewColumn: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15222760/2065611

Comment: Thanks! from the coding: thisid = rowData.getColumnValue("unid"); I think the "unid" column is the document id, but my page there is not unid.

Comment: As you want to add document's UniversalId to URL you can add an invisible column "unid" to your view or use getUniversalId() like shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patient help! I have write the coding on the second column's Server onclick Events like this:facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/"+@ReplaceSubstring(@Subset(@DbName(),-1),"\\","/") + "/0/" + rowData.getDocument.getUniversalID() + "?opendocument"); But when I click the link it display error:HTTP 500.

Comment: Why don't you use xp:link? Then you'd see the generated URL in browser howering over link. Use OpenDocument instead of opendocument.

Comment: Thanks! but still encounter error. Page Name: /xvbyDate.xsp Control id: viewColumn3 Property: onclick Script interpreter error, line=1, col=128: [ReferenceError] 'rowdata' not found -> 1: facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/"+@ReplaceSubstring(@Subset(@DbName‌​(),-1),"\\","/") + "/0/" + rowdata.getDocument.getUniversalID() + "?OpenDocument"); javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.ja‌​va:102)

Comment: Add var="rowData" to your xp:viewPanel.